# Concatenate in XSLT

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I am finding it difficult in creating XSLT for a particular XML Node. Please help in me solving this.
XML Node:

```
<field name="GOP Structure">
    <GOPStructures>
        <GOPStructure>
            <M value="0" />
            <N value="1" />
            <coverage value="3.6" />
        </GOPStructure>
        <GOPStructure>
            <Mmax value="3" />
            <Mmin value="2" />
            <N value="48" />
            <coverage value="99.9" />
        </GOPStructure>
        <GOPStructure>
              // so on..
              </GOPStructure>
    </GOPStructures>
    <AverageGOPLength value="48" /> </field>
```

The Output I want is :

`<field name="GOP Structure" value="(M=0 N=1)(  3.6%),(M=[2 .. 3] N=48)(  99.9%)" />
 <field name="Average GOP Length" value="48"/>`

A particular GOPStructure node can either have 3 child nodes( M, N and coverage) or 4 child nodes(Mmax, Mmin, N and coverage).
In case of 4 child nodes, the output XML M value should be within [Mmin..Mmax]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if  this can work for you;

```
<xsl:template match="field[@name='GOP Structure']">
    <field name="GOP Structure">
        <xsl:attribute name="value">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="GOPStructures/GOPStructure[M or Mmax]"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </field>
    <field name="Average GOP Length" value="{AverageGOPLength/@value}"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="GOPStructure[M]">
    <xsl:text>(M=</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="M/@value"/>
    <xsl:text> N=</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="N/@value"/>
    <xsl:text>)(</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="coverage/@value"/>
    <xsl:text>%)</xsl:text>
    <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="GOPStructure[Mmax]">
    <xsl:text>(M=[</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="Mmin/@value"/>
    <xsl:text>..</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="Mmax/@value"/>
    <xsl:text>] N=</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="N/@value"/>
    <xsl:text>)(</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="coverage/@value"/>
    <xsl:text>%)</xsl:text>
    <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Ok, my doubt has been cleared away. I'll remove my comments.